# GCC call graph profiling (-pg, gprof) on iOS possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, gcc, profiling, gprof

Is there a way to use GCC call graph profiling on iOS? Setting GENERATE_PROFILING_CODE in Xcode4 seems to have no effect when building for iOS devices (I also don't see -pg being passed to compiler or linker) and even if it had an effect, how would I access the gmon.out file written to the iPhone/iPad?

The Time Profiler of Instrument only samples all threads at regular intervals and thus can easily miss quick calls; even when using the smallest sampling interval possible.

**Update**:
And I'm not trying to do that to find a performance hotspot, I need an exact statistic which function has been called how many times while the program ran; the sampling needs to be exact (thus missing functions calls is a no go) and it needs to be CPU friendly (it must not waste too much CPU time compared to running the code without that profiling).

Comment: Do you get the answer? If yes please share with us.